# What could possibly be wrong with this tag edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

See my edit here.

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13614557

It has been so far rejected twice and approved once. I don't understand why someone would want to reject it, nor I can't understand why they didn't edit it. I only edited its tag. It's been rejected because of:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability

Answer (score 3):

To start with, and what is probably the biggest issue with your edit: The question looks too broad, a reason to close, and your edit doesn't even begin to fix that issue. It's never worth your time to edit a post that will likely be closed and deleted, unless your edit makes the post on topic.

Other, smaller points that don't help your edit:

- You removed the "Cheers" line, and left the "Thanks in advance." Both lines are noise and should be removed while you're cleaning up the rest of the post.
- The question is hard to read because it's a single paragraph with code written in plain text. Either breaking up the paragraph or inline code blocking the couple of methods(?) listed in the post. Both probably would've helped readability.
- I would argue that the two "view" tags you added don't help much with classification of the question, but I could also see arguments to the contrary. Depending on the reviewers' thoughts on the usefulness of those tags, that may help in their decision to reject.
- Looking at the question itself, it's an *old* question, and your edit would bump it needlessly without greatly improving the question. That could also have weighed in the reviewers' decision.

Your edit really *didn't* make the post much better, if any. The post is still off-topic, still hard to read, and still contains noise. The reject reason is certainly correct.

Comment: I see your point for the first 2 reasons. I implemented your first 2 suggestions right now. Yet an edit isn't to make a post perfect. It's only to make it better. The question's tags were very unrelated. The suggested tags made it much more related. The `viewDidLoad` & `viewWillAppear` tag are exactly what it's about. I don't understand what you're saying in your 3rd suggestion. You're forth reason is very weird. FYI there is  a medal editing old posts. Though that has nothing to do with why I made the edit. FYI it just got approved, thanks for your suggestions. btw the question wasn't broad

Comment: The question _looks_ broad. When I examined the answers, it looks like it isn't. The "pros and cons" request is what makes it _look_ broad. Had I come across that edit in review, I likely would have rejected for that myself. I tried to make it clear the third point was more opinion based, and would likely come down to the reviewer. I don't see why those two tags are useful in general, but I also have not bothered to look to see how useful they are. If I were reviewing, I might do a bit more looking into that point. (cont.)

Comment: As for the fourth, yes, you can get a badge for that, but if you're going to bring attention to an old, inactive question, it's usually best you actually make the question better, easier to read, or easier to find. This point _also_ comes a bit down to opinion of the reviewer. Your fixed suggestion looks a lot better.

Comment: Well that's were editing suggestions come into play. The user could have easily had my edit corrected. Some users are kind enough to edit, some just trash all the hard work

Comment: The two rejecters may not have seen a point to improving the edit. That _also_ comes down to opinion, and occasionally how much time the reviewer has. They also may not have felt they _could_ improve it.